# How to write the following command in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT TOP 1 
                        @isDeleted = IsDeleted, 
                        @deletedDate = Deleted   
                    FROM ' + @FullTableName +
                   'WHERE ID = ' + cast(@RowID as nvarchar(30)) + '';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, 
                         N'@isDeleted bit out N@deletedDate DATETIME out', 
                         @isDeleted out, @deletedDate out
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'N@deletedDate'

I am not sure how to write the last line.

It worked for `@isDeleted` but when I tried to add another variable `@deletedDate`, it stopped working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unnecessary `N` instead of `comma` in second parameter between the variable declaration. You need to add a single `N` before the second parameter to make the string of `NVARCHAR` type.

Try this

```
EXECUTE Sp_executesql
  @sqlCommand,
  N'@isDeleted bit out, @deletedDate DATETIME out',
  @isDeleted out,
  @deletedDate out
```

Comment: In other words, the OP is missing a comma.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Also a unnecessary `N`